# Perform face recognition on two cameras

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, face-recognition

I have a face recognition project using a camera without any problems.

I now want to do this simultaneously from two cameras.

This is my code for one camera, I haven't any idea on how to employ two cameras for this purpose.

```
import face_recognition
import cv2
import numpy as np
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture('rtsp://admin:11111@192.168.1.13:554/mode=real&idc=1&ids=2')


farid_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("farid.jpg")
farid_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(farid_image)[0]

# Load a second sample picture and learn how to recognize it.
roice_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("roice.jpg")
roice_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(roice_image)[0]

known_face_encodings = [
    farid_face_encoding,
    roice_face_encoding
]
known_face_names = [
    "farid",
    "roice"
]

while True:

    ret, frame = video_capture.read()
    rgb_frame = frame[:, :, ::-1]


    face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(rgb_frame)
    face_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(rgb_frame, face_locations)

    # Loop through each face in this frame of video
    for (top, right, bottom, left), face_encoding in zip(face_locations, face_encodings):
        # See if the face is a match for the known face(s)
        matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(known_face_encodings, face_encoding)

        name = "Unknown"

        # Calculate face distance
        face_distance = face_recognition.face_distance(known_face_encodings, face_encoding)
        # If a match was found in known_face_encodings, just use the first one.
        if True in matches:
           # first_match_index = matches.index(True)
            # Sort nearest distance
            name = known_face_names[np.argsort(face_distance)[0]]

        # Draw a box around the face
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (left, top), (right, bottom), (0, 0, 255), 2)

        # Draw a label with a name below the face
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (left, bottom - 35), (right, bottom), (0, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)
        font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX
        cv2.putText(frame, name, (left + 6, bottom - 6), font, 1.0, (255, 255, 255), 1)

    # Display the resulting image
    cv2.imshow('Video', frame)

    # Hit 'q' on the keyboard to quit!
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# Release handle to the webcam
video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I can Simply add more cameras using `cv2.VideoCapture()` module, but how can I make changes to `face_recognition` in order to work with two cameras?

Answer (score 0):

You could try making this multithreaded. One thread for each camera that does it's own facial recognition on the images that it sees.

They would be acting independently on their respective streams, but you can then get results from both threads to combine the information for improved detection and/or recognition.